# Why Changing Data Source Is Not Allowed in Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi, report, connection-string

Seems after a PBI report is deployed to PowerBI.com, the connection string cannot be updated. This is an issue if the report is built connecting to Dev database server. But need to be connected to Prod DB server after deployment. But why did Microsoft designed it this way? SSRS support updating connection string from the beginning.

Comment: Please provide more context/information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-parameters) for that.  See eg [Deployment pipelines best practices - Use parameters in your model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-best-practices#use-parameters-in-your-model)

Comment: But deployment pipeline is only available to premium license.

Comment: Parameters are available in every workspace, and there's an API to update parameters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-parameters